# javascript xmlhttp request not working when execute code on console of facebook.com tab

Tags: javascript

i want to get json array return from    http://graph.facebook.com/1mahalkita

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://graph.facebook.com/1mahalkita", true); 
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } 
 } 
 xmlhttp.send();
```

this code should work but i'm getting error when i execute this code in firefox console
error

```
[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2"  data: no]
```

how can i fix this ?
   this is screenhot

[image]
_________________________update____________________________________________________

actually code works on outher browser tab consoles .it only doesn't work when i execute from facebook tab.since i'm using this code with some other codes i have to use console on fb page 
code should execute in

Comment: It works in my Firefox console, as well as jsfiddle on Firefox, Chrome, and IE 10

Comment: It's working on Firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/e0orb0qq/35/

Comment: what?then why i'm getting this error ?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241605/exception-nsresult-0x805e0006-unknown-location-when-submitting-changes-us

Comment: What happens if you call the site in browser?

Comment: THANKS EVERY ONE PROBLEM FIXED WHEN I USE httpS://graph.facebook.com/1 INSTEAD OF HTTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to load mixed content. You'll have to use https in the get request since Facebook only uses https.

Comment: hmm but you can use http for graph api  for example http://graph.facebook.com/100003102447840 however api has update recently now access token is required for this

Comment: You can access most pages on http, doesn't mean they'll work on https pages and that's what Facebook uses. That's the reason it doesn't work, http requests on https pages causes the mixed content warning.

Comment: yes that could be the reason .but i'm not much understand deeper .

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it, hopefully this MDN page will help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent