# AJAX error on Firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

My code returns the following error :

```
"[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 4"  data: no]"
```

This error appears when I print the result of xhr.statusText into the console. Nothing shows on the Firefox browser as a result.

However, in Chromium, everything shows as expected, with no error message. I would assume there is some kind of incompatibility in Firefox. I don't know.

Did anyone ever encounter this issue ? By the way, I'm using CodePen.

Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided code or a link to CodePen

Comment: Which version of firefox? Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: Firefox 49.0
I have seen that a similar error message was due to some mcAfee plugin. I don't have any mcAfee stuff installed.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241605/exception-nsresult-0x805e0006-unknown-location-when-submitting-changes-us